# Do I add an ability modifier to base damage?

Tags: dungeon-world

In Dungeon World, if you succeed with Hack n Slash or Volley is the damage just the base damage or is the damage base damage plus the relevant strength or dexterity modifier?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Hi @bob: I don't know if you're new-ish to DW, but if you are I strongly recommend reading through [some of the site's Q&A on it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dungeon-world). Many of the answers do a great job of explaining the philosophy and practice behind the moves (unlike mine, below!), and when I was starting out they were like a tutorial in "thinking like the Apocalypse." Happy gaming!

Answer (score 18):

Ability modifiers are not, by default, added to damage. (Though they are, by the moves' description, added to the "to hit" rolls of **Hack & Slash** and **Volley**.) See, for instance, DW p.23 ("Damage"):

> If a move just says “deal damage” the character rolls their class’s damage dice plus any bonuses or penalties from moves, weapons, or effects. If a move specifies an amount of damage, use that in place of the class’s damage roll.

(Just for completeness, the distribution of class' damage dice, some advanced moves that add another die's damage, and the +*n damage* tag that a weapon might have are the common sources of variety in damage dealt. And *piercing* is kinda-damagey....)

But do remember that narrative is king. How much damage you deal is often secondary to using the fiction to put yourself in position to deal a killing blow, or to trip up a charging ogre, or spot the missing scale on Smaug's belly. The sort of combat this game is trying to replicate isn't that of a video game, where hits are traded and HP accounted-for at every second. It's the combat of a fantasy novel, describing how kicking off of a stump helps you circle behind your foe before they could react....